# API for wp menu hacks

Tags: menus, options, api, hacks

Question changed due to new developments!

I was loooking for a way to hack the menu items in the custom menu page to add a "hide" checkbox and other options. The only way I found is to override the Walker_Nav_Menu class.

I think it's a quite tricky solution...

In the wp_nav_menu codex anyway i found many examples with filters and action to hack custom menus. Nevertheless I haven't found any documentation about these hacks.

Another idea I had is to treat menu items as custom post (they are actually), so i was wondering if the custom field api could be helpful for my purposes.

Any suggestions?

OLD QUESTION:

There is one big but simple feature that is missing from WP and I really can't understand why!!!

There isn't any way to just hide front end menu items without deleting them completely!

If for example I have a complex menu with many items and submenus and i want to hide it for a while, it's not possibile to do it! Just a checkbox with a display option would be enough.

It's me missing something?

If it's really missing, is there an API to modify the Appearance>menu section to add more capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

There are several of plugins that ads that kind of functionality. They put a checkbox to the admin area, so if you uncheck it its not gonna appear in the menu.

Here is a good one:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/

Comment: The plugin you showed add the checkbox in the page administration.

I want the option in the custom menu boxes, since my menu items are not always pages!

I found a plugin that had a visibility input in the menu boxes. Looks like it is possible to do this by overriding the  Walker_Nav_Menu class. I was hoping for something simpler, like a filter or an action!